# Run program in BigEndian mode

Tags: c#, endianness

I want to debug my program in Big endian mode. currently my hardware is little endian. the program seems working fine.

I want to make sure that program works fine in big endian system because Im currently a bit confused about reversing byte arrays when reading and writing a binary file.

How can i make the program to behave like big endian system?

I tried to do it in reflection

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    typeof(BitConverter).GetRuntimeField("IsLittleEndian").SetValue(null, false);

    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian);
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 6}, 0)); 
}
```

but still it does not print `6`. In big endian system it should print 6 right? how can i simulate this?

Comment: There's a huge difference between "how BitConverter works" and "how the whole program works". Basically, you should get hold of a machine with a big-endian CLR...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the respond. is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @Amit Thanks for the respond. i have searched for the softwares to simulate big endian but i had no success.

Comment: Not being able to find anything is a pretty decent lead to you trying to solve a problem you don't have.  The little end won by a land-slide.  The only non-trivial host that is big and can execute C# code is the olden XBox 360.  You can find emulators for it or buy one at Ebay I suppose.  Then again, you should already have that if there is any realistic point in testing this.